# Jobs failed with the following errors

Tags: sql-server

this is the first time I've tried to schedule a job and I keep getting the error message below. I am using the admin account and checking the 32 bit box. Any ideas on how to remedy? Thanks.

> Executed as user: NT Service\SQLAgent$BZMSSQLSERVER. Microsoft (R) SQL
>   Server Execute Package Utility Version 14.0.2014.14 for 32-bit
>   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft. All rights reserved.
>
> Started: 9:48:28 AM Error: 2019-12-02 09:48:29.50
>
> Code: 0xC0202009
>
> Source: TEST Connection manager "DestinationConnectionExcel"
>
> Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has
>   occurred.
>
> Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available.
>
> Source: "Microsoft JET Database Engine"
>
> Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "The Microsoft Jet database engine
>   cannot open the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another
>   user or you need permission to view its data.". End Error
>
> Error: 2019-12-02 09:48:29.50
>
> Code: 0xC00291EC
>
> Source: Preparation SQL Task 1 Execute SQL Task
>
> Description: Failed to acquire connection
>   "DestinationConnectionExcel". Connection may not be configured
>   correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this
>   connection. End Error
>
> DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
>
> Started: 9:48:28 AM
>
> Finished: 9:48:29 AM Elapsed: 0.641 seconds. The package execution
>   failed. The step failed.

Comment: *'"The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user or you need permission to view its data.".'* Seems pretty self explanatory. Also, why are you using jet? Or are you using an `xls` file, rather than `xlsx`.

Comment: "It is already opened exclusively by another user " seems a pretty obvious problem. Did you have the file open and forget to close it before running the job?

Comment: Sorry, first time using sql server. No idea why it is using excel at all. I want the code to export an excel file but I do not have it open. Is it when I saved during the export wizard?

Comment: I'd like to have it run a piece of sql code and then export the results to excel to a folder. Just not sure how. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a permission issue. If you can, change the Agent service account to a Windows AD account with local admin privileges.